# What are the differences between AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 0-10?

Tags: amqp

The differences between [AMQP 0-10 and AMQP 1.0](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Messaging_Programming_Reference/Differences_between_AMQP_0-10_and_AMQP_1.0.html) are detailed over the internet.
I can't find any details or changelog on the differences between AMQP 0-9-1 and 0-10.

What are the main differences between those versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if You see at the Standard the AMQP 0-9-1 AMQP 0-10 are completely different Protocols,
the main Difference I got in these two Protocols is their Architecture.

As AMQP 0-10 provides a specification for protocol is Client and the broker Architecture(in the form of exchange, binding and queue) while on the other hand AMQP 1.0 provides only protocol specifications being completely independent to the broker, Infect AMQP 1.0  doesn't even say that there will be a broker so it completely deprecated the concept of Exchange and bindings.

in simple word, in case of AMQP 0-9-1, each connection is defined to have a Client(Producer/Consumer) and a Broker.
but in case of AMQP 0-10, there are no such constraints on the role of connection endpoints so there could be broker less Point-to-Point communication.

Comment: I don't believe this is true and thus this doesn't answer the question. You are explaining the difference between 0-9-1/0-10 and 1.0. 1.0 indeed doesn't force a central broker, but 0-10 still does. The question isn't what the difference is between 0-9-1 and 1.0 (two totally different protocols) but what was added to 0-10.